# C# Initialize Class with a List<T> property

Tags: c#, list, initializer-list

I need some help on how to initialize the below object with some sample values in the Main method to perform some action.

Since I am new to C# please guide me to where can i get this information

```
class MobOwner
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public List<string> Mobiles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply initialize it within your constrcutor:

```
class MobOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Mobiles { get; set; }
    public MobOwner() {
        this.Mobiles = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

You can also define a constructor that direclty puts the right values into your list:

```
class MobOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Mobiles { get; set; }
    public MobOwner(IEnumerable<string> values) {
        this.Mobiles = values.ToList();
    }
}
```

Which you can than call like `new MobOwner(new[] { "Mario", "Hans", "Bernd" })`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I doubt if you really want `set;` in the `Mobiles` property:
typically we add/update/remove items in the list, but not assign the list as whole

```
  MobOwner sample = new MobOwner(...);

  sample.MobOwner.Add("123");
  sample.MobOwner.Add("456");
  sample.MobOwner.RemoveAt(1);
  sample.MobOwner[0] = "789";

  sample.MobOwner = null; // we, usually, don't want such code
```

The implementation can be

```
 class MobOwner {
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public List<string> Mobiles { get; } = new List<string>();

   public MobOwner(string name, IEnumerable<string> mobiles): base() {
     if (null == name)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("name");

     if (null == mobiles)
       throw new ArgumentNullException("mobiles");

     Name = name;

     Mobiles.AddRange(mobiles); 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make and instance and set the variable

```
var owner = new MobOwner();
owner.Mobiles = new List<string>{"first", "second"};
```

or like so

```
var owner = new MobOwner {Mobiles = new List<string> {"first", "second"}};
```

recommanded way is to use a contructor and make the set properties private

```
class MobOwner
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<string> Mobiles { get; private set; }
    // constructor
    public MobOwner(string name, List<string> mobiles)
    {
        Name = name;
        Mobiles = mobiles;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates one `MobOwner` object containing a list with one item

```
MobOwner item = new MobOwner()
{
    Name = "foo",
    Mobiles = new List<string>() { "bar" }
};
```

---

Another way is to add a constructor to simplify instanciation

```
class MobOwner
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Mobiles { get; set; }

    public MobOwner(string Name, params string[] Mobiles) 
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Mobiles = new List<string>(Mobiles);
    }
}
```

usage:

```
MobOwner item2 = new MobOwner("foo", "bar", "bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mobOwner = new MobOwner()
   {
       Name = "name";
       Mobiles = new List<string>()
           {
               "mob1",
               "mob2",
               "mob3"
           };
    };
```

Comment: Thanks you all for your support. I'm going to use Dmitriy Kovalenko's reply, if I want to some more items like name2, mobA, mobB, mobC is it possible?

Comment: @rajeshnrh: note that you should really get familiar with constructors since they are made for this purpose. They ensure that you can't initialize a `MobOwner` with an invalid state. Otherwise the user of your class has to know that he has to initialize this list himself. He might try this: `var owner = new MobOwner(); owner.Mobiles.Add("mob");` which will cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: If you think my answer is correct pls mark it as a correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your purpose correctly you want to initialize these values in the "Main" method.

Constructor is a good way to initialize your properties with default values whenever you create an instance of your class.
But if you want to initialize them in another place make an instance of your class and then you can give values to its public members. like this:

```
MobOwner mobOwner = new MobOwner();
mobOwner.Name = "Jimmy";
mobOwner.Mobiles = new List<string>{119, 011};
```

or in a more modern way you can change the syntax like this(although they are the same):

```
MobOwner mobOwner = new(){
    Name = "Jimmy",
    Mobiles = new List<string>{119, 011}
};
```